# IS php same as java in terms of pass by reference?

Tags: java, php

As PHP borrows most of its object oriented features from java. I would like to know whether PHP and java both uses the same concept of pass by value?

I know Java is not pass by reference.Its just that object references are passed by value. How about PHP? Does PHP support pass by reference?

Comment: I believe that this behavior has changed as of PHP5, from default pass-by-value to default pass-by-reference-variable.

Comment: "PHP borrows most of its object oriented features from java" - what an absurd statement (and predicate on which the remainder of the post is based). You need to broaden your horizons Chandu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you only pass stuff by reference if you declare a function and litter it with ampersands:

```
function &return_by_reference() {
    $something = make_something();
    return $something;
}

function increment(&$n) {
    // This changes $n because it is a reference parameter
    $n++;
}
```

There is call-time pass-by-reference as well (i.e. passing variables by reference when you *call* functions), but I shan't go on about it because it presents a risk for unexpected behavior. It's better practice to declare parameters to be passed by reference in your function signatures instead.

As for objects: in PHP 4, objects are all passed by value. In PHP 5, references to objects are passed by value, just like in Java.

Comment: Does that come with an increase in performance in, say, a recursive method? (due to the lack of copying a bunch of member variables)

Comment: @Christian Mann: the data is copied on demand when it is really necessary. It is called "copy-on-write" principle. "bunch of member variables" --- Or are you talking about objects? If so - in php5 all objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @Christian: The Zend Engine is copy-on-write by default so if you use references for stuff like this, the engine will have to keep track of these references and things will get pretty bad if it recurses too much.